# Удалить устаревшие записи из таблицы, оставив только пять последних

Tags: mysql, sql

Пусть имеется таблица сообщений, снабженных датой публикации `createad_at`. Задача состоит в выполнении такого запроса `DELETE`, в результате выполнения которого в таблице бы осталось 5 последних по времени записи.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS posts (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  created_at date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO posts VALUES
(1, 'первая запись', '2012-11-01'),
(2, 'вторая запись', '2012-11-02'),
(3, 'третья запись', '2012-11-03'),
(4, 'четвертая запись', '2012-11-04'),
(5, 'пятая запись', '2012-11-05'),
(6, 'шестая запись', '2012-11-06'),
(7, 'седьмая запись', '2012-11-07'),
(8, 'восьмая запись', '2012-11-08'),
(9, 'девятая запись', '2012-11-09'),
(10, 'десятая запись', '2012-11-10'),
(11, 'одинадцатая запись', '2012-11-11'),
(12, 'двенадцатая запись', '2012-11-12'),
(13, 'тринадцатая запись', '2012-11-13'),
(14, 'четырнадцатая запись', '2012-11-14'),
(15, 'пятнадцатая запись', '2012-11-15'),
(16, 'шестнадцатая запись', '2012-11-16'),
(17, 'семнадцатая запись', '2012-11-17'),
(18, 'восемнадцатая запись', '2012-11-18'),
(19, 'девятнадцатая запись', '2012-11-19'),
(20, 'двадцатая запись', '2012-11-20');
```

Хорошо бы задачу решить при помощи одного запроса. Предполагается, что количество записей в таблице произвольное.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению limit в mysql не позволяет подставлять в него непосредственно переменные или подзапросы. Так же MySQL не позволяет использовать offset в операторе DELETE. Зато MySQL позволяет использовать привязываемые переменные при предварительной подготовке запросов.

```
prepare stmt from "delete from posts order by created_at limit ?";
set @cnt=(select count(1)-5 from posts);
execute stmt using @cnt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Первое что приходит в голову, это просто отсортировать записи в прямом порядке и удалить 20 - 5 = 15 записей

```
DELETE FROM
  posts
ORDER BY
  created_at
LIMIT 15
```

Однако, фактически это решение задачи в два запроса, так как у нас не всегда будет 20 записей, для вычислений количества записей в таблице потребуется дополнительный запрос.

Можно получить дату `created_at` пятой с конца таблицы записи и удалить все записи, ранее этой даты

```
DELETE FROM
  posts
WHERE
  posts.created_at < (SELECT
                created_at
              FROM
                posts
              ORDER BY
                created_at DESC
              LIMIT 5, 1)
```

Однако, в MySQL последний запрос не сработает и вернет ошибку

> 1093 - Не допускается указание таблицы 'posts' в списке таблиц FROM для внесения в нее изменений

Для того, чтобы воспользоваться этим решением, придется воспользоваться самообъединение таблицы и выполнить многотабличный оператор `DELETE`

```
DELETE
  posts
FROM
  posts
JOIN
 (SELECT
    created_at
  FROM
    posts
  ORDER BY
    created_at DESC
  LIMIT 5, 1) AS delpst
ON
  posts.created_at <= delpst.created_at
```

Существуют вариации решения, например, можно предварительно создать представление `VIEW`, которое будет "знать" дату пятой записи с конца последовательности или задействовать переменную сеанса, в которую предварительно эта дата сохранена.

Comment: А вы уверены, что даты не могут повторяться у разных записей? Иначе вы можете оставить не то кол-во записей. Я бы объединял и потом удалял по null id

Comment: @splash58 Да, согласен. У меня первоначальный вариант был именно с id, но в последний момент переправил на created_at. В принципе сейчас MySQL позволяет сохранят значения даты и времени с милисекундами, можно некоторое время ориентироваться на эту точность. Однако, если поток данных слишком велик, created_at в запросах лучше заменить на id.

Comment: Да и заодно обратите внимание, что ваш запрос на вашей схеме работать не будет :)

Comment: @splash58 спасибо! поправил.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант №2 -

```
START TRANSACTION;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE limited (
  id INT
);

INSERT INTO limited
SELECT id
FROM posts
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 5;

DELETE FROM posts
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM limited);

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE limited;

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Так возвращает ошибку #1235 - Эта версия MySQL пока еще не поддерживает 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'. В MySQL не получится использовать в DELETE вложенные запросы с обращением к таблице, из которой удаляются записи. И похоже поддержку уже не введут никогда (это сообщение получено на последней MySQL 5.7 и ситуация не меняется уже 10 лет).

Comment: @cheops, а если подзапрос поименовать?

Comment: Так обмануть тоже не получится, видимо у MySQL какое-то курсорное удаление - не позволяющие нормально использовать вложенные запросы. Они перед продажей компании Sun проделали большую работу на то, чтобы привести СУБД в соответствие к стандарту SQL. Однако, поправить вложенные запросы в DELETE и UPDATE так и не смогли.

Comment: @Ok зайдем с другой стороны

Comment: @Mirdin немного поправил второй вариант, чтобы он в MySQL выполнялся. В принципе тоже решение, пусть и не в один запрос. Еще можно, чтобы не создавать временную таблицу, действовать через `CREATE VIEW` создать представление и ориентироваться на него.

Comment: @cheops, спасибо. Что касается VIEW, то по мне временная таблица более специфический инструмент для подобных задач.

Comment: @Mirdin мне кажется если задача разовая, то да - временная таблица идеальное решение, если периодическая, то возможно готовое представление не будет лишним.