# Оставить в БД только n записей

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Задание такое: в базе должно храниться не более 12 записей.
Есть очень элегантное решение для этого
`DELETE FROM news WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12)` ,
но в моей версии MySQL якобы не поддерживается LIMIT в подзапросах. Какой выход можно найти из этой ситуации?

Comment: Создать 12 пустых записей, и вместо вставки новой выполнять обновление самой старой.

Comment: Можно триггер написать, который удаляет старые записи при добавлении новых.

Comment: @Akina, немного непонятно..

Comment: Что именно непонятно? В таблице сразу создаётся нужное количество записей, и к ней применяются ТОЛЬКО запросы SELECT и UPDATE, никаких INSERT или DELETE. И ещё есть вариант - оформить подзапрос как представление, тогда LIMIT допустим.

Comment: @Alex78191 Триггер не позволит изменять таблицу, на изменение которой он сработал.

Comment: @Akina в смысле?

Comment: А такой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545560/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85/545582#545582 подход в вашей версии MySQL работает ?