# SQL подсчёт количества связанных записей

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, связи

## Подсчёт связанных записей

Доброго времени суток!
Использую СУБД MySQL в связке с PhpMyAdmin, при создании связей между таблицами появился вопрос: "Можно ли получить количество записей в других таблицах, связанных с некоторой записью используя лишь sql".

### Пример

Предположим у нас три таблицы: Авторы, Книги и Журналы. Авторы-Книги (1:М), Авторы-Журналы (1:М). В таблице Авторы есть некий Иванов, с котором имеется 10 записей в таблице Журналы и 3 записи в таблице Книги. 

Возможно ли получить количество связных записей с господином Ивановым? (их 13 = 10 журналов + 3 Книги)

При том что, количество таблиц не известно, результат необходимо получить с помощью языка SQL, без использования триггеров и т.п.

Comment: что значит "количество таблиц не известно", вы же сказали в начале, что их три ... А количество получается с помощью count и да, разумеется можно получить с помощью него нужные количества из нужных таблиц (строго определенных в запросе)

Comment: Три таблицы было приведено в качестве примера, не правильно сформулировал, нужно было использовать фразу несколько таблиц n.
Ну как видно из ответа и комментария, в sql нет решения для подсчёта данной задачи, без использования строгих запросов. Спасибо за ответы и комментарии.

Comment: тогда вам поможет только динамическое составление запроса из списка таблиц. Можно на клиенте заранее по списку таблиц подготовить или прямо в SQL, сначала подготовить текст запроса, а потом выполнить его execute как в этом примере https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/545560/545582#545582  хотя в первую очередь напрашивается конечно изменение структуры БД, слияние книг-журналов в одну таблицу

Answer (score 1):

```
Шаблон:

SELECT main.id
     , COUNT(DISTINCT slave1.id) count1
     , COUNT(DISTINCT slave2.id) count2 
  /* , ... */
FROM main
/* some */ JOIN slave1 ON main.joinfield1 = slave1.joinfield1
/* some */ JOIN slave2 ON main.joinfield2 = slave1.joinfield2
/* ... */
```

Если нужно ещё и общее количество - то можно сложить соответствующие COUNT-ы. А если нужно только общее количество - лучше в подзапросах получить COUNT по каждой отдельной таблице в отдельном подзапросе, и только потом суммировать.