# Как получить медиану в mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица test, в неё автоматически заполняются значение id, speed, как получить медиану значения speed в mysql

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql более простого способа, чем там в принятом ответе для mysql я не вижу

Comment: хотя более быстрый может и придумаю. там полный проход таблицы в заданной сортировке, а в принципе достаточно дойти до середины

Comment: хотя если быстрее, то в 2 запроса, первым получить количество записей в переменную, вторым сделать выборку с limit на это количество ...

Comment: Не понимаю как это всё связывать, Select count(Speed) AS speed From test; а далее как

Comment: лучше в переменную на клиенте получить количество и потом эту переменную подставить в запрос вида `select avg(speed) from (select speed from table order by speed limit количество/2,2) X` если целиком в MySQL то придется идти через prepare/execute (как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545582/194569) потому что переменную в limit использовать нельзя

Comment: @Mike Это если количество чётно. В общем случае `limit (количество-1)\2,2-количество%2`.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/… более простого способа, чем там в принятом ответе для mysql я не вижу – Mike 25 авг в 11:37

Answer (score 0):

Если необходимо среднее вообще по всем - `SELECT id, avg(speed) FROM tablename;`

Если же под id подразумевается id какой-либо строки в другой таблице и они могут повторяться, а нужно среднее для элементов с одним id - то так `SELECT id, avg(speed) FROM tablename GROUP BY id;`

Comment: id автоинкремент. Медиана - это все значения выставляются по возрастанию, из них берутся 2 значения из самой середины,суммируются,и высчитываются ср значение этой суммы