# Динамическое имя таблицы в триггере

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть триггер, который копирует столбцы из одной таблицы в другую. 
Как присвоить имя таблицы динамической переменной `@nametable`? Каждый день имя таблицы меняется в зависимости от текущей даты.

Пробовал делать так:

```
USE dbo;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `update_test`;

GO

DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER `update_test` AFTER INSERT ON `hello_send`

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

DECLARE nametable VARCHAR(128);

SET @nametable =(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%d%m%Y_v"));

    INSERT INTO `dbo`.`nametable` SET
      `TIME_` =NEW.`recorded`,
      `P1` = NEW.`value1`
   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        `TIME_` = NEW.`recorded`,
       `P1` = NEW.`value1`;

END;
```

Выдает  `ERROR 1146: Table 'dbo.nametable' doesn't exist`.

Comment: Зачем менять каждый день имя таблицы? Может лучше менять имя бд?

Comment: Есть внешние приложение которое работает с данными таблицами и на которое я не могу повлиять, данные за день сохраняются в отдельной таблице имя которой текущая дата+ _v.

Comment: конструируйте текст всего запроса в текстовой переменной и выполняйте его с помощью execute. вот как тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545582/194569 например

Answer (score 0):

Решил сделать так , как временное решение:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `update_test` AFTER INSERT ON `hello_send`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @dateNameTableNOW =(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%d%m%Y_v"));
SET @dateNameTableSELECT1 = '06122017_v';
SET @dateNameTableSELECT2 = '07122017_v';
IF(@dateNameTableNOW = @dateNameTableSELECT1) THEN
 INSERT INTO  dbo.06122017_v  SET TIME_=NEW.recorded, P1 = NEW.value1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TIME_ = NEW.recorded, P1 = NEW.value1;
END IF;

IF(@dateNameTableNOW = @dateNameTableSELECT2) THEN
 INSERT INTO  dbo.07122017_v  SET TIME_=NEW.recorded, P1 = NEW.value1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TIME_ = NEW.recorded, P1 = NEW.value1;
END IF;


END;
```

Answer (score -1):

Попробовал сделать внутри процедуры

```
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dinamicTable;

DELIMITER $$  
CREATE PROCEDURE dinamicTable()
BEGIN
 SET @nametable =(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%d%m%Y_v")); 

SET @stmt = CONCAT( 
'CREATE TRIGGER ''update_test' 
'AFTER INSERT ON' 'hello_send' 
'FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO ',@nametable ,'SET' 'TIME_=NEW.recorded, P1 = NEW.value1' 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE' 'TIME_ = NEW.recorded, P1 = NEW.value1');

PREPARE stmt5 FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt5;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt5;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Получаю ошибку `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''update_testAFTER INSERT ONhello_sendFOR EACH ROW BEGIN     INSERT INTO 04122017' at line 1    0.000 sec`

Пожалуйста ткните носом как надо, SQL изучаю две недели и больше недели вожусь с данной, казалось бы банальной проблеммой.
Вопрос?
Если получится сделать в процедуре как тогда вызывать ее при добавлении новой строки в таблицу `hello_send`.

Comment: Не надо триггер создавать в процедуре. триггер же на одну таблицу.  создавайте его один раз как изначально и планировали, просто внутри него собирайте текст insert в текстовой переменной, что то вроде `concat('insert into ',@nametable,' ...')` и тут же выполняйте динамически именно этот insert. И не надо продолжение вопроса писать в ответы. В ответах должны быть только ответы

Comment: @Mike7 Делал так `DROP trigger IF EXISTS update_test;
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER ``update_test` `AFTER INSERT ON` `hello_send`
`FOR EACH ROW`

`BEGIN
SET @nametable =(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),"%d%m%Y_v"));
SET @stmt = CONCAT(' INSERT INTO ' ,@nametable, ' SET '   'TIME_=NEW.recorded, P1 = NEW.value1' ' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ' 'TIME_ = NEW.recorded, P1 = NEW.value1'); `
`PREPARE stmt5 FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt5;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt5; 
 
END;` , получаю ошибку `Error Code: 1336. Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger`

Comment: К сожалению в этом сообщении об ошибке все сказано. я этого не знал. сейчас посмотрел интернет ... динамический sql невозможно выполнять в триггерах либо хранимых процедурах. ваша задача не решаема средствами MySQL. Все, что вы можете сделать, это фиксировать факт изменения записей (с помощью поля timestamp или триггерами) и в отдельной процедуре, написанной на любом внешнем языке перегружать данные в нужные таблицы. или добавлять соответствующий код в процедуры, модифицирующие таблицу hello_send