# Одним запросом получить записи по OFFSET и кол-во записей до

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица публикаций, которая отображается на странице запросом вида

```
select * from table where <всякие_условия> order by pub_date desc limit off, lim
```

Список длинный - несколько тысяч. Хотелось бы добавить возможность позиционироваться в нем по месяцу и году. Т.е., пользователь указывает, например, `январь 2015` и попадает на 30 страницу.

Но в запросе

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
    cross join (
      select (@cnt := 25*ceil(count(*)/25)) cnt  from mytable
          where pub_date > '2015-01-01'  
      ) tt
    order by pub_date desc    
    limit <что бы сюда подставить>, 25
```

limit выдает ошибку, если там стоит `select...` , `cnt`, `@cnt`

MySQl ругается на cnt в offset. А можно как-то его обмануть, или два запроса делать придётся?

Comment: А как вы узнаете страницу из такого запроса? Запрос же будет возвращать данные без указания страниц.

Comment: @Visman это я решил :) вопрос обновлен

Comment: А offset на несколько тысяч БД не напрягает ? Уйти бы от offset при пагинации ...

Comment: @Mike Про это на habrahabr видел статью с техникой. Надо будет освежить

Comment: Если записи за старые периоды редко удаляются я бы наверное хранил порядковые номера. правда их неудобно вести и главное, придется перенумеровывать при удалении чего либо. Зато при выборке можно спокойно использовать count()-номер для определения страницы. А count() mysql хранит и не вычисляет каждый раз

Comment: @Mike Практически, можно сказать, что не удаляются. Кстати, ваш запрос сходу заработал -  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95f3e9/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В limit нельзя подставлять ничего. Обойти это ограничение можно только динамическими запросами, как например [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545582/194569).

Учитывая, что вам надо не только выбрать данные, но и показать клиенту, что он находится на 30 странице (что бы он мог после позиционирования по дате перейти на 29 или 31). Предлагаю все таки делать это отдельным запросом, сначала вычислить номер страницы, а потом уже делать выборку обычным способом, исходя из этого номера.

Но если все таки хочется одним запросом, то можно попробовать что то в этом роде:

```
select *
  from mytable,
       ( select max(pub_date) pub_date, max(id) id
           from (
              select pub_date, id, @cnt:=@cnt+1 NR
                from mytable, (select @cnt:=0) a
               where pub_date>(@need_date:='2018-01-01')
               order by pub_date
               limit 25
           ) X
         where NR=(select count(1) % 25 from mytable where pub_date>'2018-01-01')
       ) Start
  where (mytable.pub_date<coalesce(Start.pub_date,@need_date) OR
         (mytable.pub_date=coalesce(Start.pub_date,@need_date) and mytable.id<=coalesce(Start.id,0) )
        )
 order by mytable.pub_date desc
 limit 0,25
```

Тут мы выбираем и нумеруем записи одной страницы, находящиеся непосредственно перед искомой. По номеру записи, равному остатку от деления кол-ва записей на размер страницы (количество записей перед искомой на текущей странице), узнаем ее дату и id. id получен на тот случай, если на странице несколько записей с абсолютно одинаковой датой. Таким образом мы узнали дату и id первой записи на требуемой нам странице и можем использовать их в обычном условии where с указанием нулевого смещения в offset.

Comment: я, честно говоря, надеялся, что я какой-нибудь хитрости не знаю. А сейчас посмотрев, на это всё, склоняюсь к тому, что лишний запрос будет даже лучше. Хотя само по себе ваше решение офигенное.

Comment: @splash58, на тестовом примере при `2017-12-09`, `2017-12-15`  выдает не то, что ожидалось, кажется. У меня же пустой ответ в таких случаях. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95f3e9/17

Comment: @Mike. похоже, он не любит ситуации, когда попадает на край страницы. Надо поковыряться

Comment: @splash58 Похоже там надо строго меньше поменять на меньше или равно: `t1.pub<=coalesce(Start.pub,@need_date)`. только надо проверить на другие ситуации. В этом случае подзапрос дает NULL и срабатывает вторая часть у coalesce... Там наверное логика с id за ту же дату нарушится в таком случае. И условие придется усложнять типа `(Start.pub is null and t1.pub<=@need_date) OR (Start.pub is not null and t1.pub<Start.pub) OR ...`

Comment: Я через время посижу,  тоже поковыряюсь - любопытно

Answer (score 1):

Вот, что-то такое вышло:

```
SET @var1:=0;
SELECT r.nrow, p.*
FROM `posts` AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT IF(posted < 1203781710, @var1:=@var1+1, @var1) AS nrow, id
    FROM `posts`
) AS r ON r.id=p.id
WHERE (25*FLOOR(@var1/25))<r.nrow
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 25
```

Запрос тестировал на своей базе, так что наименование таблиц и столбцов мои.
`@var1` для подсчета строк таблицы пока их время создания меньше заданного в условии `IF(posted < 1203781710, @var1:=@var1+1, @var1)`. В итоговую выборку берем только строки со страницы с последней записью, где `posted < 1203781710` -> это `(25*FLOOR(@var1/25))<r.nrow` вычисление первой записи на этой странице (**возможно тут есть неточность на +-1 запись!** нужно тестировать с проверкой).

**UPD** изменил сортировку и формулу расчета страниц

```
SET @var1:=0;
SELECT r.nrow, p.*
FROM  t1 AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT IF(pub >= '2017-12-01', @var1:=@var1+1, @var1) AS nrow, id
    FROM t1
    ORDER BY pub DESC
) AS r ON r.id=p.id
WHERE (3*(CEILING(@var1/3)-1))<r.nrow
ORDER BY pub DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95f3e9/72

Comment: посмотрите - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95f3e9/9

Comment: @splash58, открыл снова и обновил.

Comment: Очень похоже, что все работает. Не могу еще upvote'нуть к сожалению :)